# Why does my index.html file lose its color syntax?

Tags: html, syntax, colors, format

I'm using Atom for small HTML/JS projects, and something odd keeps happening. My html file will lose the color coded syntax so all the text is black/grey. I've noticed this mostly happens when I try to add script tags at the bottom, or when I copy/paste in bootstrap links at the top.

Sometimes it will leave individual lines of code with the correct coloring, which I find even stranger. Like the whole file will be in black/white but the final  tag is still red.

I've tried to troubleshoot by changing the language at the bottom, which does nothing. I've also tried creating new files, copying/pasting the code instead of typing it. All the questions/answers I've found on Stackoverflow have been regarding custom syntax coloring, not what to do if your file loses its color.

Examples: if I use the most basic html template by typing 'html' and letting it autofill. All the text will be in the correct coloring. But then if I autofill "src" or "scr", or manually type  it will turn either portions of the font or the entire font black. Often if I close and re-open the file, or copy/paste identical text in, it will fix the problem.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could post the code here

Answer (score 0):

as you said final tag still is red , and it shows colors on some lines there might be a problem with quotes,
**incomplete quotes or brackets usually** creates such problems.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I don't think it's being caused by incomplete quotes or brackets. For example in the code above, if I add a <style></style> tag at the end, it turns the entire document black. If I copy/delete/paste the whole page, it is back to the correct coloring with no changes to the actual code